# Trouble with removing part of string and creating variables in R

Tags: r, string, variables

I have few variables with _mean in their name. I want to find these variables and remove _mean from their name whilst creating  a variable moment = mean for them. I use the code below:

```
for (i in 1:length(files)){                                   #looping through files 
  dflist[[i]] <- read.dta13(files[i], nonint.factors = TRUE)  #reading the files into R

  if(grepl("_mean", colnames(dflist[[i]])) == TRUE){  #locating variables with _mean
    dflist[[i]]$moment <- "mean"                   #creating moment=mean variable
    str_replace(dflist[[i]], "\\_mean.*", "")}    #removing _mean from string names
}
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
1: In if (grepl("_mean", colnames(dflist[[i]])) == TRUE) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and no adjustments are made to the variable.

Output should look like:
Before

```
|variable1_mean|variable2_mean|
|24            |25            |
```

After

```
|moment| variable1 | variable2|
|mean  |   24      |     25   |
```

Comment: use `sub` i.e. `names(df1) <- sub("\\_.*", "", names(df1))` and `df1$moment <- "mean"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `sub`

```
names(df1) <- sub("_.*", "", names(df1))
df1$moment <- "mean"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
names <- colnames(df)
for (i in 1:length(names))
{
  names[i] <- gsub("_mean", "", names[i])
}
colnames(df) <- names
```

Instead of the `for` loop you can also use one of the `apply` functions